# How is the Catmull Clark algorithm calculated mathematically in Blender?

Tags: subdivision-surface

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catmull%E2%80%93Clark_subdivision_surface

When I tried to find the location of the 'new vertex point' using the algorithm in the link above, the results were not the same as the results I got in Blender when I applied the  subdivision modifier.

Is this because Blender uses opensubdiv to calculate the mesh division?
If so, what formula does opensubdiv use to get the 'new vertex point'?
I want to find the coordinates of the 'new vertex point' with a formula that only takes the coordinates of each vertex in the mesh as input.
This nagging question has been bothering me for weeks. Please help me out.